# How do I configure Nwazet Commerce with Orchard 1.7.2?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I'm trying to install Nwazet Commerce with Orchard 1.7.2.

Suddenly, nothing happens. No new menus, no errors, nothing in the logs, nothing. It is just as if I hadn't installed it.

Before you ask... yes I've enabled the modules.
[image: All modules enabled]

I can't find even a single scrap of documentation. What is supposed to happen? I would expect to see some extra menus or something on my dashboard or perhaps some extra content types, but there's nothing.

Help please :-|

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The current version in the source repository is only compatible with the 1.x branch. See https://bitbucket.org/bleroy/nwazet.commerce/issue/20/update-to-17

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. I pulled the 1.x branch and I have been able to get it mostly working. When I go through the checkout process though, url stripe/checkout just comes up with a 404 error. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to configure SSL. Stripe won't work without an encrypted connection.

Answer (score 0):

I have a version for 1.7.2 unfortunately I don't know what fork it was from so I don't know what bugs or issues were included.

I found it in my saved orchard files and tested quickly you will get the admin options.

Download available [here](http://orchard-cms.com/orchard-modules)